# How can I traverse the list of a class A within a classA?

Tags: c#, list

I have a class called FilterType. Inside this class I have a list of a same   class as a data member. I'm trying to loop though each and every member of the list and the list within the list. This is my code.

```
public class FilterType
{
    string name;
    int id;
    string OR;// Either "OR" or AND only one condition is true.
    string AND;//
    List<FilterType> fl = new List<FilterType>();
}
```

I have started with something like this:

```
if(fl.count>0)
{
}
```

I'm not sure how to go through each and every member in this list. Let me know if any one has any suggestion.

Comment: How deep does this recursive structure go? _Using FT for FilterType_, you have an FT that contains a list of FT, each of which has a list of FT, and so on. This is a simple `tree structure`. If you look up how to traverse or walk a tree, you should find many solutions.

Comment: Yes you right. This is a recursive structure. The recursive loop will go until you find ft.count =0. Example: If we have L (say root) and inside L, we have L1, L2, L3 and so on. And inside L1, we have L11, L12,L13...so on.

Comment: Then for first recursive call we will go from L => L1 => L11. Each time we make a recursive call we check if the there are any items inside the list before it calls its child node. I hope I haven't confused you more. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you are looking for is recursive iteration. A lot of data structure (trees) would need similar functionality. You can do it using loops:

```
        private static void Recurse(List<FilterType> fl)
        {
            foreach (var item in fl)
            {
                //do whatever you want with the current item, am just setting the name again
                item.name = "Looped through";

                //Go through the child list
                Recurse(item.fl);
            }
        }
```

Or you can do it using the SelectMany linq operator (think of selectMany equivalent of a loop within loop), and then iterate over the flattendList doing what you want.

```
 var flattendList= root.fl.SelectMany(f => f.fl);
```

Do be careful with the recursion, if your data is big then the code might not be performant and there are chances that it might throw out of memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is loop, you can use any of the loop elements of the C# language:

foreach(var item in fl)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.GetType());
}

Or the for expression to iterate using indexes

for(var i = 0; i < fl.Count; I++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fl[i].GetType());
}

Hope this help!

PS: sorry for the editing, writing from my mobile

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enumerate recursively, you can do it bu using `yield return`.

```
public IEnumerable<FilterType> EnumerateRecursively()
{
    yield return this;

    foreach (var item in fl)
    {
        foreach (var subItem in item.EnumerateRecursively())
        {
            yield return subItem;
        }
    }
}
```

C# make it relatively trivial to do that without intermediate accumulation and without having to write a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly you wanna achieve

If you just want to loop the list fl, there are many ways to do it.

I would use foreach loop like this.

```
foreach (var item in fl)
{
   // Do something with item.
}
```

and if you want to loop the list outside of the class.

Rather than setting the list to public.

It is recommended that you create a function inside the class that does something with a 'list' outside the class.

I mean, if you want to do something with the list lf like this outside of the class

```
if(FilterType.fl.Count > 0)
{
   // Do something.
}
```

I would recommend that you create a function like this inside the class

```
public class FilterType
{
   string name;
   int id;
   List<FilterType> fl = new List<FilterType>();

   public bool IsEmpty()
   {
      return fl.Count > 0 ? false : true;
   }
}
```

and use it outside of the class like this.

```
if(filterType.IsEmpty())
{
   // Do something.
}
```

I hope this answer can help you.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above code is used to gerate OR and AND filter type.

Comment: ( Sorry I accidently hit "enter" before finished typing ) I then travers through the List and generate a mathematical expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum LogicalOperator { OR, AND }

public class FilterType
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int id {get;set}
    public LogicalOperator ConditionType {get;set;}

    public List<FilterType> fl {get;private set;} = new List<FilterType>();

    public IEnumerable<FilterType> Descendants {
        get 
        {
            foreach(var f in fl)
            {
                yield return f;
                foreach(var child in f.Descendants)
                {
                    yield return child;
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```